# Tribe Events and Avada Wordpress Theme Show Category Name Only - tribe_get_event_categories()

Tags: wordpress, events, calendar

I have been researching a solution and I have found that I can use:

`tribe_get_event_categories()`

but it adds "Event Category:" and a bullet point to my category.
I just want it to show the Category name, without the bullet or "Event Category:"

http://new.jjsgrill.com/ is where you can see how its currently behaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:
**Function: tribe_get_event_categories** > https://theeventscalendar.com/function/tribe_get_event_categories/

So maybe you could try something like...

```
tribe_get_event_categories($event->ID, array(   'echo'         => false,
                                                'label'        => '',
                                                'label_before' => '',
                                                'label_after'  => '',
                                                'wrap_before'  => '',
                                                'wrap_after'   => '',
                                            ));
```

Comment: https://theeventscalendar.com/support/forums/topic/display-just-category-name/